# Number of possible states of a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ Tic Tac Toe board

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible game states are there for a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ tic tac toe game?
Assuming the rules are that player X and O alternate one move at a time.

Comment: What symmetries or equivalences are you permitting?  If a state is rotated 90 degrees, is that the "same" to you?   Are you allowing states that can never be achieved in a true game, such as three blacks in a row and three whites in a row?

Comment: What if there is a winner before all 'squares' (boxes?) have been filled?  Should we stop the game at that point?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork without considering rotation the same state. Only realistic states that can be achieved in a real game.

Comment: @Bram28 yes, the game should stop if there is a winner before all the boxes are full.

Comment: if this is too difficult to calculate, an approximation of how much less than 3^27 would be appreciated as well :)

Comment: I just wrote a program playing lots of games until either one player wins or the board is completely filled. Considering that player 1 is playing crosses, the program converged at 5690 states.
An alternative approach was enumerating all 3**9 possible states (each cell can be empty or played by either player) and eliminating the illegal states. States are illegal if
- there are more naughts than crosses
- there are two or more crosses more than naughts
- either player has more than once three in a row
- both players have (at least) three in a row
This approach results in 5670 states.
The latter

Comment: See http://www.mathrec.org/old/2002jan/solutions.html